# Java Scratch Pad for Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

Often times I find myself wanting to test a statement, regex, or other simple Java statement, without having to write a test class and deploy the entire app.

I believe something like this exists in Eclipse, but is there something like this for Netbeans, or perhaps an online expression tester?

In the past, I've used [this](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) online PHP tester, which is very convenient.  Something like this for Java would be nice as well.

Comment: Haven't heard about such thing but I usually go for "psvm" + [TAB] which creates a public static void main class then I copy paste the statement and run the file. That saves me a ton of time as clean/build and deploy takes forever for larger projects.

Comment: Just found this one, which is mostly what I want.  http://ideone.com/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote http://jpad.io for exactly this purpose.

[image]

I wanted to run java snippets without all the bloat, I also wanted to see the results nicely displayed.